# Setting apartment state for using WatIn with MSTest

Tags: visual-studio-2010, nunit, mstest, watin, webtest

I am getting the following error in:

The CurrentThread needs to have it's ApartmentState set to ApartmentState.STA to be able to automate Internet Explorer.

With the following code:

```
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {

    [AssemblyInitialize]
    public static void AssemblySetup(TestContext context)
    {

    }

    [TestMethod]
    [HostType("ASP.NET")]
    [AspNetDevelopmentServerHost("C:\\SomePath", "/")]
    [UrlToTest("http://localhost/HomeView.aspx")]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        using(IE ie = new IE("http://localhost/HomeView.aspx",true))
        {
            ie.TextField(Find.ById("MainContent_txtDLNumber")).TypeText("a235801945550");
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a different approach for using WatIn with MsTest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will probably need to adjust your config accordingly, below should give you a clue

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="NUnit">
      <section name="TestRunner" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler"/>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <NUnit>
    <TestRunner>
      <!-- Valid values are STA,MTA. Others ignored. -->
      <add key="ApartmentState" value="STA" />
    </TestRunner>
  </NUnit>


</configuration>
```

Comment: This is correct. Actually, I was using the resharper test runner which required the same config settings as the Nunit test runner.

Comment: @japrram: should the question tag be updated to list nunit instead of mstest?

Answer (score 0):

Consider updating your code to use NUnit 2.5 with [RequiresSTA](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=requiresSTA&r=2.5) attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] args)
{
}
```